# The complement of a Zariski open dense subset in a real linear algebraic group has zero Haar measure?

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a real linear algebraic group (so it is locally compact and Hausdorff), equipped with a left-invariant Haar measure. Let $U$ be a Zariski open dense subset of $G$. I wonder how to show that $G-U$ has zero Haar measure?

My idea is that maybe we can first show that $G-U$ is contained in some lower dimensional manifold and conclude that it has zero Haar measure, but I don't know how to realize this more formally.

Comment: What do you mean by Haar measure on an algebraic group. Usually one takes points in some topological ring and topologizes $G(R)$ as a subgroup of $\GL_n(R)$. In particular, if you have a non-Hausdorff topological group, like G with the Zariski topology, is there even a version of Haar’s theorem?

Comment: @StefanDawydiak sorry I should be more clear. The group I am considering should always be locally compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: Maybe you could use Sard's Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from Sergei Ivanov’s rather stronger answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25519). Density is not needed, only the fact that Haar measure is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.